# Show data using highchart bar graph where categories are dynamic date which comes with data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Show data using highchart bar graph where categories are dynamic date which comes with data.

My code to show data on graph:

```
function highchartDate(Male,Female) {
   Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%e of %b'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Day Shift',
            data: Male
        }, {
            name: 'Night Shift',
            data: Female
        }]
    });

};
```

where Male and Female are the array of arrays like

```
Male = [[1508803200000, 41][1509235200000, 44][1509408000000, 44]]

Female =[[1508803200000, 41][1509235200000, 44][1509408000000, 44]]
```

when i run this code on fiddle it works fine but not in project I noticed the reason but don't get the way to make it worked in code. 
Can any one help me in this getting the data displayed on graph properly.
this is the Link where you get the code which run fine if i put the value in data seperated with commas like [[1508803200000, 41],[1509235200000, 44],[1509408000000, 44]] .this works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/Pookool/k1qua683/1/

@Kamil Kulig can you help me in this or any one else

Comment: That is not valid json. It needs the commas to separate the values

Comment: Its a array. not json value

Comment: **ITS NOT VALID!** You need a comma to separate the values in an array. And it **IS** json (or javascript array)

Comment: I don't quite understand what is a problem here. This demo seems to work fine when you provide the appropriately formatted data array: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/jsa4dtmk/

Comment: Thanks @kamil for the help. 
I parse the Array to JSON in the format which chart expect and got the value on graph properly.